# how to change image back to original state when when back is pressed in android

Tags: android, eclipse-adt

the thing is i have made an application in which icons are there.. when we click on icon, it changes its image.. (i.e it glows). and open another activity.. but when back is pressed, its still in glowing state.. so i want to revert it to original statewhen back is pressed

```
package sditm.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class page1 extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
ImageView about;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.page1);


    about=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView6);



    about.setClickable(true);




   about.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-gener2ated method stub
            about.setImageResource(R.drawable.helps);
            Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),aboutActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter all fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            about.setImageResource(R.drawable.help);

        }
    });



}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `onResume()` to restore image previous state:

```
 @Override  
    protected void onResume() {  
        about.setImageResource(R.drawable.imageView6);
        super.onResume();  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your main activity override onResume() method and do what you actually want when back is pressed and then try.

Answer (score 0):

Just Go through this [Activity Life Cycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

You can also use onResume() which can help you when you want return back to the Activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can finish the current activity and start again this activity in OnbackPressed(). This method will call when you press back button. or You can try to use onTouch event for icon image as

```
about.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            {
                 about.setImageResource(R.drawable.help);

                 Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),aboutActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);


            }
            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                 about.setImageResource(R.drawable.help);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

It may help you..

Answer (score 0):

you can use selector to define different images for different states, say normal, focused, pressed.

Else you can use onStart method, this methods would get invoked whenever your activity would be on window.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ImageView use can use button, and that you can make custom to change the button color or image in each event... follow this link.. [Click here](http://www.learntoprogram.tv/2011/11/21/android-development-creating-custom-buttons/)